# Invertibility of Grammian in Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Space

Tags: functional-analysis, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space with a reproducing kernel $K:X \times X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. For any finite sequence $x_1,...,x_n$ of distinct points in $X$ we define Gramm matrix as
$$
M(x_1,...,x_n) := 
 \begin{pmatrix}
  K(x_1,x_1) & \cdots & K(x_1,x_n) \\
  \vdots    & \ddots & \vdots  \\
  K(x_n,x_1) & \cdots & K(x_n,x_n) 
 \end{pmatrix}
.$$

In reading one the articles from this field the author notes that the invertibility of matrix $M$ is safely assumed due to [Mercer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercer%27s_theorem). When looking up the theorem I was not able to conclude this by myself. Can somebody point out to me, how exactly does the invertibility follows from the theorem?